# dataframe-go: How to filter using < > operators?

Tags: dataframe, go

I'm trying to do a simple filter in `dataframe-go`. I adapted from the Github example and tried to use a simple `>` operator in the Filter Function, but the compiler gave `invalid operation: vals["day"] > 4 (operator > not defined on interface)` error (see my code below)

Ok, so I changed the type to `map[string]int64` but then, it gave the error: `cannot convert func literal (type func(map[string]int64, int, int) (dataframe.FilterAction, error)) to type dataframe.FilterDataFrameFn`.

I'm very familiar with R DataFrame/Table and Pandas but `dataframe-go`'s API is rather convoluted. The only web resource I found is [this](https://mungingdata.com/go/dataframes-gota-qframe/) but the author also stated he couldn't understand the filter API.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
    s1 := dataframe.NewSeriesInt64("day", nil, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
    s2 := dataframe.NewSeriesFloat64("sales", nil, 50.3, 23.4, 56.2, nil, nil, 84.2, 72, 89)
    df := dataframe.NewDataFrame(s1, s2)

    // Try filtering
    filterFn := dataframe.FilterDataFrameFn(
        func(vals map[string]int64, row, nRows int) (dataframe.FilterAction, error) {
        //func(vals map[interface{}]interface{}, row, nRows int) (dataframe.FilterAction, error) {
        if vals["day"] > 4 {  // <= This is where I changed things
            return dataframe.KEEP, nil
        }
        return dataframe.DROP, nil
        })

    ctx := context.Background()
    dt_filtered, _ := dataframe.Filter(ctx, df, filterFn)

    fmt.Print(dt_filtered)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a function with the required signature, so `vals` must be a `map[interface{}]interface{}`. This is required because Go is not an interpreted language, and the code calling that function you passed as an argument has no compile-time knowledge of the function passed in.

Since your values are `interface{}`s, you have to convert them to the correct type to operate with them:

```
if ivalue, ok:=vals["day"].(int64); ok { // Check if the value is int64, and go ahead if so
    if ivalue > 4 { 
       return dataframe.KEEP, nil
    }
}
```